# highlight text input upon accesskey

Tags: javascript, html, focus, access-keys

I have an HTML page with a text input field for a search string. I would like to give focus to the field when the user hits a predefined key (like META-S).

A similar behaviour is possible for anchors in HTML 5:

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css3" accesskey="c">CSS3</a>
```

I am wondering if there is a more specific solution than to have a JS function listening to all key presses and filtering for the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should already be using `<label />` for all your form inputs (for accessibility purposes) .. `<label />` can have the `accesskey` attribute.

Example:

```
<label for="search" accesskey="s">Search:</label><br />
<input type="text" id="search" width="100" />
```